# Insert or update in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have a staging table TABLENAME_STG(ID, COL1, COL2) where data is being dumped from an external system. Then I need to run a command that will grab that data and dump it into the actual table TABLENAME(ID, COL1, COL2, COL3).
The issue is that some data might already exist so I want to update it, if the data is new I want to insert. I have looked into REPLACE INTO, however this command deletes the existing row and inserts a new one which would cause the loss of COL3 data. Something like this.

```
REPLACE INTO TABLENAME(COL1, COL2, COL3) SELECT COL1, COL2, FROM TABLENAME_STG WHERE COL1 = VAL1 AND COL2 = VAL2.
```

I thought about doing an insert into on duplicate key but if I understand the command, it only checks if the primary key is a duplicate which wouldn't be the case in my scenario. Unfortunately a record is unique based on multiple columns like COL2 and COL3. Is there way to tell the below statement to update if the duplicate keys exist based on the columns I choose as my unique values?

```
INSERT INTO TABLENAME(ID, COL1, COL2, COL3) VALUES(SELECT ID, COL1, COL2, FROM TABLENAME_STG WHERE COL1 = VAL1 AND COL2 = VAL2) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE UPDATE COL1=COL1, COL2=COL2;
```

Comment: How did you form that understanding, and how might you test its veracity?

Comment: @Strawberry, I formed it mainly from not being a SQL developer. All my knowledge revolves around simple queries and views. Hence why I'm here

Answer (score -1):

Use a SELECT statement to first pull the data, look at it and perform your condition checks, and then either do an INSERT or UPDATE respectively.